# Does using NSCache to cache image downloads waste memory as NSURLSession ready caches?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsurlsession, nsurlcache, nscache

I know `NSURLSession` uses `NSURLCache` to cache HTTP responses, so if I use `NSCache` to cache image downloads due to its own advantages, am I having two copies in memory for each cache, and thus being wasteful?

If so, how do I stop `NSURLSession` from caching in memory automatically? (I still want the persistent store caching though.)

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom `NSURLCache` object with zero or just few bytes of memory. And than set it as shared cache to prevent memory usage.

```
NSURLCache * cache = [[NSURLCache alloc]initWithMemoryCapacity:1024 diskCapacity:1024*1024 diskPath:nil];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:cache];
```

[Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLCache_Class/Reference/Reference.html)